# How to install a Hyperledger Fabric network in distributed mode (on multiple machines)

Tags: architecture, distributed, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After running Hyperledger fabric samples, it seems that all peer nodes are run as docker containers, but all of them are running on same machine. So if I configure a network having 12 peers, it will be 12 docker containers running on same machine?
Can we create a network, where peers will run on different machines? Say, each peer run as one or multiple docker containers on separate machines? How that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this link useful

https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/

Comment: It has the required source code , steps to set up peers in multiple machines